# Can't find ArcGIS Online Portal on my home computer w/ ArcGIS Pro uni license

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am getting into ArcGIS Pro using these tutorials https://learn.arcgis.com/en/paths/try-arcgis-pro/?rmedium=links_esri_com_j_r&rsource=https%3A%2F%2Flinks.esri.com%2Flearn-try-arcgis-pro I discovered a problem when trying out the first and second tutorials called Singapore Tourism and Explore Data respectively.

The problem is I don't see "ArcGIS Online" as a Portal, and thus have trouble finding the data needed for the tutorials. However, I have something called "All Portal", where I found the data for Singapore Tourism and Explore Data (called "explore your data"). So it should work, right? The problem for the second tutorial is that "explore the data" can only be found when I open the data through "Open Another Project", but not by "add data" when I am inside a project. This was not a problem for the Singapore Tourism data, however.

The weirdest thing is that, according to instructions, you add Portals through the Portal Menu. But when I go there, I already see the Portal for ArcGIS Online (called arcgis.com). Isnt that weird? It is like the Portal is registered, I can access its files, at least sometimes, but I dont see it on the list, and it doesn't really work as intended... ? See screens that I provided below.

[image: my portals]

[image: ArcGIS Online should be active as a Portal?]

Comment: What is the issue? You will see the connection to arcgis.com, as you are using a named user license being fetched from ArcGIS Online. Reframe the question and specify your issue. Also do not get confused with ArcGIS Online and Portal. Portal is also referred to as ArcGIS Enterprise. 
Reframe the query to specify what is the exact concern, and if you only want the data for tutorial check this https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/pro-quickstart-tutorials.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_51AE25B88185490BBEAEB1B9A31B3D88

Comment: Clarification:
The arcgis.com connection is there, but ArcGIS Online is not showing up among the Portals. Instead I find the required data in "All Portal". But it does not work 100% when I want to Add Data into an existing project.

So the issue is that there is a vagueness of if I have a normal connection to ArcGIS Online, or if there is a problem.

Comment: ArcGIS Online **is** ArcGIS.com.  It's the same thing. So your default portal of https://www.arcgis.com is what you should be using. UNLESS, you're talking about launching ArcGIS Pro while at University and they've created their own portal and strangely named it "ArcGIS Online". In that case, you may not have access to that from your home network. But this seems unlikely. I think you're probably just confusing the name(s) and expecting to see something different.